# How to post JSON object angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

I would like post object and read it on node server but I have an error.

**controller :**

```
$scope.update = function(contact) {
console.log(contact);
    $http.post('/contactlist/' + contact).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);

    });
};
```

**server node :**

```
app.post('/contactlist/:contact', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json();
});
```

**server node head:**

```
var express =  require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var connection = *****************

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

**Screenshot of the error network POST :** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epU2r.png)

**server error of console.log(req.body);**

`[object Object]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing any parameter in your post API. POST needs a parameter to be passed and since you are passing the parameter in the request URL, you can try by passing an empty object like this:

```
 $http.post('/contactlist/' + contact,{}).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);

    });
```

You are trying to concatenate an object in the URL which is not a good approach. If you want to still do this way, stringify it and then append it to URL. And you can get it with the help of `req.query`. But it is better if you change the url and pass contact as a parameter to your API call.

**Problem solved by :**

```
var OBJ = JSON.stringify(yourOBJ);
```

Comment: I think you are passing an array contact

Comment: You need to stringify the array before

Comment: How do you know if it's an array? chrome say: 
Object {id: 571, name: "QSDF", email: "QSDFQSD", number: "FQSDF"}

it's not JSON?

Comment: It is a JSON only and not an array but you have to handle it correctly. If it is an object, why don't you pass it as $http.post('/contactlist/' , contact).then(function(response) 
{
    console.log(response);

}); And change your nodejs code

Comment: I stringified but I have another problem cause I have 2 post into differrent scope.
$scope.add
$scope.update
Node server results the first one of server.js ( post from add ).
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Ask as another question :)

Comment: I asked another question, check it :)

Answer (score 1):

For node js there different syntax please see below:

```
var yourObj = {}; 
$http.post('/contactlist/' + contact, {data: yourObj}).then(function(response) 
{
    console.log(response);

});
```

This will work